# My question was deleted by the community account. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

I asked a question a week ago but I can see in my profile [that the question has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151179/hi-i-want-to-convert-my-xls-file-into-pdf-using-apache-poi) by the community account.

May I know why that happened?

Answer (score 12):

This is the answer on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).  The relevant bit is:

---

**If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**

- not closed as a duplicate
- has a score of 0 or less
- is not locked
- has no answers with a score > 0
- has no accepted answer
- has no pending reopen votes
- has not been edited in the past 9 days

... it will be automatically deleted:

---

So if you want to avoid having your question deleted, then you should consider editing it.  If it has been nearly nine days since you asked the question, then you'll have had plenty of opportunity to read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you may have stumbled across hints on how to edit your code to make it more useful to answerers either [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [elsewhere](http://www.sscce.org/), and of course you've spent plenty of time searching for other questions that already have answers to your question.

Comment: And the key message here is ... if your question gets closed (other than as a duplicate), and you don't want it to get deleted, then edit it to make it better.